# Why is there only 1 way to pick 4 digits that match?

Tags: probability

This question is from Rosen's Discrete Math textbook 7th edition:

In a lottery, players win a large prize when they pick four digits that match, in the correct order, four digits selected by a random mechanical process. A smaller prize is won if only three digits are matched. What is the probability that a player wins the large prize? What is the probability that a player wins the small prize?

The answer given is:

There is only one way to choose all four digits correctly. By the product rule, there are 10 4 = 10,000 ways to choose four digits. Hence, the probability that a player wins the large prize is 1/10,000 = 0.0001.

My concern is, why is there only one way to choose the 4 digits correctly? Shouldn't there be 10 possibl outcomes for when all the digits match? 0000, 1111, 2222, ... , 9999. So can somebody explain this to me? I think I might have misread or misunderstood some things... thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you stopped reading the first sentence after "...when they pick four digits that match".

Comment: You're right. I just noticed that the numbers should match the numbers generated  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, this is a lottery. The winning number is $4567$ for example. And the only way to pick that number is: $4567$.

If the winning number is $1111$, then picking $0000$ is not picking the winning number.

You are not matching the numbers with themselves, you're matching them with the winning number.

Comment: Ahhh i see! How silly of me. Thanks for pointing it out! 